# iBeacon CLLocationManager Background Monitoring Stops Working After a While

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon

I have an app that uses iBeacons and allows location monitoring when the app is in the background. When the app is first placed into the background, monitoring works correctly (I get `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` callbacks as the user moves around). It seems that this continues to work correctly for some time.

However, after some time (e.g., the next morning), the app seems to stop receiving location updates. I have `locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` set to `false`. Is anything else I need to do to allow long running monitoring updates in the background?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail how you are testing this?  What exactly do you see and do when you say "monitoring works correctly (I get location updates)".  Similarly, what do you do and see that is different when you say "he app seems to stop receiving location updates"?

Comment: My testing is empirical - my app receives `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` callbacks when moving between iBeacons while in the background. However, after enough time has passed (e.g., overnight) it seems to stop receiving these callbacks. It's difficult to determine exactly how long this takes to happen because its on the order of hours.

Comment: How do you know it stops receiving callbacks?  Do you have the device hooked up to XCode and you don't see NSLog statements?  Do you not get local that you trigger on these events?  I ask because what you are describing should not happen, so I am wondering if perhaps the events are firing but what you are using to determine they are firing is not happening.

Comment: I just realized that I wasn't calling `requestAlwaysAuthorization()` on the CLLocationManager. Is it possible that iOS was killing my application after a while and wasn't able to re-launch it when a location update happened because I wasn't making that call? To elaborate on your question - I can tell that I'm not receiving those updates from my application logs.

Comment: Well, if you do not call.requestAlwaysAuthorization() , it should never detect in the background, even after a few seconds.  Is this what you saw?

Comment: For region monitoring, it is required that you use requestAlwaysAuthorization().

Comment: I had the request always authorization setting in the plist file, but wasn't calling it on the CLLocationManager. I was still able to get background notifications even without calling it on the CLLocationManager.

Comment: @davidgyoung yes, I was seeing background updates without explicitly calling that CLLocationManager function. I did, however, have the `.plist` value set.

Comment: Update: I was incorrect previously - I was calling `requestAlwaysAuthorization`, so this clears up some of the confusion that I created.